# Tracking Google Analytics Cookie Accept Reject button clicks

Tags: google-analytics-4, gtag.js, cookieconsent

I have a website used by European clients (Italy, Norway, England, Netherlands). A cookie consent popup is displayed when user visit the site. I wanted to track how many users Accepted the cookies and number of users Declined.
[image]

On click of Accept Button Can I send an event to Google Analytics e.g.

```
gtag('event', 'select_content', {
  content_type: 'button',
  item_id: 'cookieacceptbutton',
  country_code :'UK'
});
```

and on click of Reject Button

```
gtag('event', 'select_content', {
  content_type: 'button',
  item_id: 'cookierejectbutton',
  country_code :'UK'
});
```

or is there any better way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The concept is correct so if you define those parameter names it's fine.

The structure of an event with gtag in GA4 is in fact the following:

```
gtag('event', <event_name>, {
    <parameter_1>: <parameter_1_value>,
    <parameter_2>: <parameter_2_value>,
    <parameter_3>: <parameter_3_value>,
    ...
});
```